# CSS how to get vertical scroll bar in dynamically populated div column

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, scrollbar, overflow

I got 2 floating columns:

```
<div class="content">
    <form method="post" autocomplete="off" action="">
        <h3>
New
</h3>
<div class='lineContainer'>
<div class="left"> 
<table id=form class='form-container lefttable'>
                <tbody>
                ...
                </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="history" class="right">
<h3>History</h3>
<table>
      <th>Date:</th><th>Note</th>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="add" />
    </form>
</div>
```

styled like this:

```
.lineContainer {
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
width:100%;
}
.lineContainer div {
display:table-cell;
#border:1px solid black;
height:10px;
padding:10px;
}
.left {
width:100px;
}
#history table{
width:100%;
height:inherit;
overflow: auto;
}
#history table tbody{
height: inherit;
overflow: auto;
}
div#history{
max-height: 300px;
overflow:scroll;
height:300px;
}
#history table th:first-child{
width:150px;
}
```

The history table is populated via AJAX:

```
$('div#history td').remove()
            $.get('some url,{some params},
            function(data){
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('div#history table').append('<tr><td>'+item.data+'</td>  <td>'+item.note+'</td></tr>');
                        })
            });
```

I want second table to have constant height with scroll if needed and can't get the scrollbar to work. Right div and table just stretch to make room for content.

I assume is because of ajax?
How to do it the way that will work on any desktop browser?

Comment: you don't have a link to a functional site that's using this code by any chance do you?

Comment: Nope - internal company system, But this is cropped copy paste. If I cropped something relevant make me know.

Comment: well, you have overflow:scroll; on div#history, what if you change that to overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll.

Comment: tried that. I also removed table and table tbody rules for clarity.
After removing `.lineContainer div` rule I got scroll but right column now overlaps the left one. I think I got to change the approach on making columns to make this work. Any other way to make the left column fixed width and right filling rest of parent div width?